# PhP using explode and replacing strings in a large file

Tags: php, replace

I'm very very new to PHP so any help will do :-)

I want to change `--` to `:` in a large file. What have I done wrong?

```
$handle = fopen('april.log.txt', 'r');

while  (!feof($handle)){
 $line = fgets($handle, 1024);
 $to_replace =array('--',':');
 $clean = str_replace($to_replace,':',$line);
 echo $line;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to replace already-existing `:` characters with `:`?

Answer (score 5):

You are printing the old string:

```
echo $line;
```

You need to print the modified string:

```
echo $clean;
```

And you can change your `$to_replace` to:

```
$to_replace = '--';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('yourfile.txt', 'r');

while  (!feof($handle)){
 $line = fgets($handle, 1024);
 $line = str_replace('--',':',$line);
 echo $line;
}
```

2 things:

- You don't need to have your search-replace in an array.
- You assigned the result of `str_replace` in `$clean` instrad of `$line`